# How can i validate an XML feed before parsing it with simplexml_load_file in PHP?

Tags: php, xml, feed

I am doing this at the moment

```
<?php   

     $xml = simplexml_load_file('www.tompeters.com/atom.xml');                  
     print_r($xml);

?>
```

but it returns this error

Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity "www.tompeters.com/atom.xml"

I think it is because the feed isn't valid XML?
So how can I validate it so I can parse the feed?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parsing the feed *is*  validating it.

Anyway, the error message looks more like that you don't have access to that file. I don't know PHP, but I would have expected at least

```
simplexml_load_file('http://www.tompeters.com/atom.xml');
```

Comment: Hi ! Just tested this solution, working. you need to tell php which protocol it must use for loading the file (here : http://). If you still want to validate a XML document from a DTD, you can use [domdocument::validate()](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/domdocument.validate.php). You can also use [DomDocument::schemaValidate](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/domdocument.schemavalidate.php) if you need to validate your file against a XSD file.